# Time isn't synchronize with server, causing cloning cert error

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm setting up a honeypot for my boss, and I'm coming across an issue with actually getting the time to synchronize with my workstations time (the reason I want to achieve this is because before looking at the steps on the link below, I had NOOBS rasbian OS installed which had the same issue with not being able to clone, but after doing the following command `sudo apt-get install ntp`, I was able to clone the files into the system with no issues, but because the link below calls for the "Rasbian Stretch Lite OS", I had to re-do the process, and because of this I can't seem to get the time to sync anymore.

https://github.com/DShield-ISC/dshield

So when I attempt to do the following command in the steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/DShield-ISC/dshield.git

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/DShield-ISC/dshield.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

I've Tried the following methods with no luck:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop
sudo raspi-config (setting timezone)
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start
```

the `timedatectl` settings are as follows:

```
Local time: Mon 2016-02-04 12:04:52 PST
Universal time: Mon 2016-02-04 20:04:52 UTC
RTC time: n/a
Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800)
Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
RTC in local TZ: no
```

Also i've tried..

```
sudo ntpd -q -g
```

I've noticed with this command I get a ton of results, and the process never finishes, if this is vital I can re-run the command and tell you what kind of information is coming back to me.

Yes I've set the time to be as close as possible to the actual clock before attempting any of these, I've noticed that regardless it's always either a minute or some seconds off, whenever rebooting. I'm assuming that's because it isn't synchronized even though it states that it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cert error was due to me being HARDWIRED into my RBI verses using wifi, after going into `sudo raspi-config`, and setting up a wifi connection I was able to successfully clone the github repo.